# Как получить название проигрываемой песни из любого плеера на xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Пишу приложение-контроллер для Android на Xamarin. По bluetooth подключается к arduino, с которой нужно управлять музыкальным плеером телефона. Возможно ли как-нибудь получить название играющей песни вне зависимости от плеера?

Пример функционала: приложение Galaxy Wearable от самсунг, отправляющее данные о композиции на часы.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11250078/12888024

Comment: http://alejandroruizvarela.blogspot.com/2014/04/get-current-song-information-with.html?m=1